# Cannot deserialize json array into object using restsharp

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

here is my JSON response:

```
     [
{
    "Id": 25,
    "CreateDate": "2020-09-26T12:25:27.917",
    "Title": "Second TV Repair",
    "categoryTitle": "Tv Repair",
    "FirstName": "Sample FirsName",
    "LastName": "Sample LastName"
} ]
```

here is my deserilizer class:

```
    public class ServicemanHistory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string categoryTitle { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my restsharp request method:

```
    public static async Task<List<ServicemanHistory>> getServiceManHistory()
    {
        string url = "https://myapi.net";
        string token = Settings.token;
        var client = new RestClient(url);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        var response = await client.ExecuteAsync<List<ServicemanHistory>>(request);
        Console.WriteLine("**** response is:" + response.Content); 
        if(response.IsSuccessful)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SUCCESS!!!");
            return response.Data; 
        } else
        {
            return null; 
        }
    }
```

I get success printed in my console and I get the json returned from response.Content, but response.Data is always null. I did the same using NewtonSoft and that didn't fix it. And I tried using a wrapper for JSON array inside my deserializer class and didn't work either.

My attempt using NewtonSoft:

```
    public static async Task<List<ServicemanHistory>> getServiceManHistory()
    {
        string url = "https://myapi.net";
        string token = Settings.token;
        var client = new RestClient(url);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
        Console.WriteLine("**** response is:" + response.Content);
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ServicemanHistory>>(response.Content); 
        if(response.IsSuccessful)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SUCCESS!!!");
            return result; 
        } else
        {
            return null; 
        }
    }
```

I get the following error when trying to deserialize using NewtonSoft:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException
> Message=Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List
> o fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Comment: Can you please show us what have you attempted with NewtonSoft ?

Comment: edited my answer and added the NewtonSoft bit.

Comment: Json you provided [works fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iFSGrx) for me.

Comment: Looks like your `Content` actually holds single element, i.e. `var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServicemanHistory>(response.Content)`

Comment: But its an array of json objects.

Comment: Error clearly states otherwise.

Comment: I changed my code to what you stated and still getting that error.

Comment: When you run `Console.WriteLine("**** response is:" + response.Content);`, what does `response.Content` look like? is it identical to what you posted at the top of the question? Or any differences at all?

Comment: If it is actually array you should get similar but different error. Is it possible that endpoint can return both single element and array based on some conditions?

Comment: @ADyson yes its exactly like the JSON: ` I/mono-stdout(19280): **** response is:[{"Id":25,"CreateDate":"2020-09-26T12:25:27.917","Title":"Second TV Repair","categoryTitle":"Tv Repair","FirstName":"Sample FirstName","LastName":"Sample LastName"}] `

Comment: If the response is like that then Newtonsoft would not crash - demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7HM0kD . Something about what you're reporting doesn't make sense.

Comment: I can send you a screen shot of the exception I get while trying to print : data.Count

Comment: There are already two reproducers here which clearly prove that your deserialization code works with provided json.

Comment: Its working now!

Comment: That's great. So...what was the real cause? did you have to change anything else?

Comment: @ADyson for some reason I didnt get the data.Count from my method. changed it to data[0].Title and got the json value. will do some further testing to see what was the cause of my problem.